# GRPC client using with node js facing issue

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node

I am facing an issue when I am trying to create a grpc client call using node js. when I use `import "google/api/annotations.proto"` in proto file I get an below error. if I remove it it works file. May I know what I am missing from my client.js

> Error: unresolvable extensions: 'extend google.protobuf.MethodOptions' in .google.api
> at Root.resolveAll (src/github.com/workspace/explorer/node_modules/protobufjs/src/root.js:255:15)
> at Object.loadSync (/src/github.com/workspace/explorer/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:224:16)
> at Object. (/src/github.com/workspace/explorer/server/grpc/client.js:3:37)

```
syntax = 'proto3';

import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

package chain;

service chain {
  
  rpc GetHeight(HeightRequest) returns(HeightResponse) { option (google.api.http).get = "/api/height/{height}";}
 
}

message HeightRequest {
  string hash = 1;
}

message HeightResponse {
  int64 height=1;
}
```

client.js

```
var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/proto/chain.proto';
var parseArgs = require('minimist');
var grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
var protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH,
    {
        keepCase: true,
        longs: String,
        enums: String,
        defaults: true,
        oneofs: true,

    });
var chain_proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).chain;

function main() {
    var argv = parseArgs(process.argv.slice(2), {
        string: 'target'
    });
    var target;
    if (argv.target) {
        target = argv.target;
    } else {
        target = 'localhost:9040';
    }
    var client = new chain_proto.chain(target,
        grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

    client.GetHeight(function (err, response) {
        console.log('height:', response);
    });
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the above error, you need to create a folder inside the project directory `googleapis->google->api` then need to add an annotation.proto file from grpc-gateway GitHub  like mention in this link
[Grpc-gateway](https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/tutorials/adding_annotations/#using-protoc)

Next need to add a path as shown below.

```
 PROTO_PATH,
    {
        keepCase: true,
        longs: String,
        enums: String,
        defaults: true,
        oneofs: true,
        includeDirs: [
            __dirname + '/googleapis',
        ]

    });
```